# Docker container "Cannot find module 'randomstring'" with node

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I am trying to run a docker container from an image created from the `Dockerfile` below

I run this command to create the image:

`docker build -t myimage .`

I run this command to start the container:

`docker run --name mycontainer -d -p 3000:3000 myimage`

However, the container immediately exits, and when I view the logs with:

`docker logs mycontainer`

an error is given:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'randomstring'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/service/dist/client/installationRawClient.js:24:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/service/dist/container.js:57:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
```

Using Node version 16.16.0 and performing a local `npm install` gives me a `randomstring` package at version 1.3.0.

`Dockerfile`:

```
# Build Layer
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine AS build
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    python3 \
    make \
    g++

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN npm install

RUN npm ci
RUN apk update && apk add bash

RUN npm run build
RUN npm run test:unit

RUN npm prune --production

# Second Layer
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine
RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /usr/src/service

COPY --from=build ./src/node_modules node_modules
COPY --from=build ./src/dist dist

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s \
            --timeout=5s \
            --retries=6 \
            CMD curl -fs http://localhost:3000/ || exit 1

USER node

ENV TZ UTC

CMD ["node", "./dist/index.js"]
```

Expecting container to stay up and have no package dependency issues.

Comment: check your source code, have you tried to import any package named `randomstring` ?.

Comment: Make sure you're not copying in the `node_modules` folder from your host system. Add it to a `.dockerignore` file

Comment: Thanks both, these comments made me realise I had started using this package in non test code for the first time, so only had it imported in devDependencies of package.json. I actually can get away without it in 'prod' code, so have removed it and it's sorted the issue